# Applying matching function to each RDD element

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this:

```
(0,List(pablo, luca))
(1,List(marco))
(3,List(anna))
(2,List(fobi))
```

and I want to substituite every single Int (0, 1, 2, 3) with a corresponding string like ("zero", "one", "two", "tree"):

```
(zero,List(pablo, luca))
(uno,List(marco))
(tree,List(anna))
(due,List(fobi))
```

So for this goal I'm using this:

```
finalCommunitiesDetectedRdd: RDD[(Int, Seq[String])] = ...

def getNameOfBin(id: Int): String = id match {
    case 0  => "Low SA Users:"
    case 1  => "Medium-Low SA Users:"
    case 2  => "Medium-High SA Users:"
    case 3  => "High SA Users:"
    case other => "nothing" // what to do if nothing else matches
}

var finalCommunitiesDetectedWithNamesRdd: RDD[(String, Seq[String])] = finalCommunitiesDetectedRdd.map{ case (id, Seq(username)) => (getNameOfBin(id), Seq(username)) }

finalCommunitiesDetectedWithNamesRdd.foreach(println) // check
```

But I obtain:

18/01/20 10:38:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 49.0 (TID 26)
scala.MatchError: (0,List(pablo, luca)) (of class scala.Tuple2)

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Seq(username)` will only match sequences with exactly one element. If you don't care about the second element of your tuple just match like this:

```
case (id, seq) => (getNameOfBin(id), seq)
```